# npm scripts don't find files in node_modules/.bin

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-scripts

I have npm scripts that run webpack

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --display-error-details --progress --config webpack.dev.config.js",
    "build:prod": "webpack --display-error-details --config webpack.prod.config.js",
  }
```

Webpack installs fine and I can see the symlink in node_modules/.bin

Locally I can do an npm run build and it works, however on the production server it fails with:

```
/bin/sh: 1: webpack: not found
```

I can run node_modules/.bin/webpack and everything works.

Output of npm config ls looks nearly identical local vs server (same npm and node versions)

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v8.10.0 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/ubuntu/.npmrc
script-shell = "/bin/sh"

; builtin config undefined
globalconfig = "/etc/npmrc"
globalignorefile = "/etc/npmignore"
prefix = "/usr/local"

; node bin location = /usr/bin/node
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the day, it was because npm run doesn't work in directories containing a colon, because $PATH is delimited with colons.

[npm issue here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13174)

Comment: After three months of chasing this bug, this is it. I can't believe it. I thought my entire npm installation was broken and reinstalled it 3 times, and was about to give up entirely. Thank you so much for posting this answer!!!